# APDS-9253 reads all data registers as 0

Tags: avr, i2c, light-sensor, xmega

I'm trying to read data from an [APDS-9253](https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/APDS-9253-001-DS) with an xmega.
My i2c bus is working because I'm reading other devices without any problem.

From the datasheet it seems at power-up the sensor is not activated: `LS_EN` is 0.
Here my flow:

1. write 0x06 at address 0x00 (`MAIN_CTRL`)
2. read registers

I get these values:

```
reg[0x00] = 0x06 // correct
reg[0x01] = 0x36 // reserved
reg[0x02] = 0x08 // reserved
reg[0x03] = 0x05 // reserved
reg[0x04] = 0x22 // correct
reg[0x05] = 0x01 // correct
reg[0x06] = 0xC2 // correct
reg[0x07] = 0x20 // correct? it should be 0x20 only the first time
reg[0x08] = 0x00 // reserved
reg[0x09] = 0x00 // reserved
reg[0x0A] = 0x00 // no data
reg[0x0B] = 0x00
reg[0x0C] = 0x00
...
reg[0x15] = 0x00
```

There are four weird behaviors:

1. I can readback the `MAIN_CTRL` register (0x00) just after writing to it, otherwise always reads as 0x00
2. the `MAIN_STATUS` register (0x07) is always 0x20 after writing the `MAIN_CTRL` register. Otherwise it changes to 0x00 - as I would expect anyway
3. the `LS DATA STATUS` bit in the `MAIN_STATUS` register is always 0, as it never has new data available
4. in any case, the data registers (0x0A -> 0x15) are always 0x00

Am I missing anything in the configuration of the registers?

Comment: Without having read all of the data sheet, I think you need to write to the `MAIN_CTRL` to enable the sensor.

Comment: @thebusybee, please read point 1. of my question: "write 0x06 at address 0x00 (MAIN_CTRL)".

Comment: Ah, I overread this, sorry. -- Did you try to enable `LS_INT_EN`? -- The data sheet is quite short on documentation of the operation. :-(

Comment: @thebusybee, tried right now. If I write to the `INT_CFG` register only I can read back what I've written. But after enabling the sensor (with `LS_EN` in `MAIN_CTRL`) also `INT_CFG` goes back to the default vaule. It seems it resets itself.

Comment: I tried with different boards and sensors, so it cannot be a damaged one.

Comment: It *seems* to work if I also set bit 0 in `MAIN_CTRL`. But this bit is reserved! It's not a problem of the bus because all the other registers are written/read correctly.

Comment: Uh-oh, I "love" such _well documented_ devices... Good luck!